# C++ CUDA project not compiling in VS2012, error on "<<<"

Tags: c++, cuda

i have a little problem with compiling a "Hello world" CUDA program in VisualStudio2012. I have downloaded and example from Nvidia:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__device__ const char *STR = "HELLO WORLD!";
const char STR_LENGTH = 12;

__global__ void hello()
{
    printf("%c\n", STR[threadIdx.x % STR_LENGTH]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int num_threads = STR_LENGTH;
    int num_blocks = 1;
    hello<<<num_blocks,num_threads>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

I changed the build configuration to cuda 6.0, added include and library paths in project properties. Still, it gave me one error in this line:

```
hello<<<num_blocks,num_threads>>>();
```

It reacts to <<<, telling me that there is an expression expected. Is there a way to fix this? It's driving me mad for the last few hours.

EDIT:

I changed the Item type of the file to "CUDA C/C++" in properties>general. Now it compiles, but with errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CUDATest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file CUDATest.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\CUDATest.cu.obj "C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest\CUDATest.cu" 
1>nvcc : warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
1>C:/Users/Rafa│/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/CUDATest/CUDATest/CUDATest.cu(15): error : calling a __host__ function("printf") from a __global__ function("hello") is not allowed
1>  CUDATest.cu
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.0.targets(597,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\CUDATest.cu.obj "C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest\CUDATest.cu"" exited with code 2.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And if i comment the printf function, then i just get something like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CUDATest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Compiling CUDA source file CUDATest.cu...
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\CUDATest.cu.obj "C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest\CUDATest.cu" 
1>nvcc : warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
1>ptxas : fatal error : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
1>  CUDATest.cu
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.0.targets(597,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\CUDATest.cu.obj "C:\Users\Rafał\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CUDATest\CUDATest\CUDATest.cu"" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Is this just a red underline in the editor, or an actual compile error?  Please provide the actual error output from visual studio when you compile the project.

Comment: How did you name the file? MSVC can be picky about `.cpp` vs. `.cu`. Also, can you explain what exactly you mean with "I changed the build configuration to cuda 6.0?"

Comment: It is an underline in the editor. The error is "Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : '<'"

The file is names CUDATest.cpp. I right clicked the project in the solutions explorer and chose "build customizations...". Then i checked the box by CUDA 6.0.

Comment: You should rename your test file from `CUDATest.cpp` to `CUDATest.cu` to make `nvcc` intercept it.

Comment: I tried that a few minutes ago, sadly it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What happens when you actually compile the program with the file as a .cu file? Paste the compile output into the question.  The red underline is an intellisense issue and does not prevent you from attempting to compile the program.  If the compile is successful, then it's just an intellisense issue.

Comment: It won't even compile, the compiler just states that there was an error. And the only error is the one i mentioned, "Error 1 error C2059: syntax error : '<". The output is:

1>------ Build started: Project: CUDATest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  CUDATest.cu
1>c:\users\(PROJECTPATH)\cudatest\cudatest\cudatest.cu(22): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I made some edits in the main post, please take a look at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to run that example, however your GPU needs to have compute capability >=2.0.

Right click on project and choose "Properties".

Go to CUDA/C++ -> Device.

On "Code Generation" replace what you have with "compute_20,sm_20" (quotes for clarity).

EDIT (regarding `Ptx assembly aborted due to errors` ): If you remove the `__device__` qualifier from `const char *STR` it should compile. (When you have commented out the `printf` function) - That was the reason for the ptxas error.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Now both of the author's problems should be solved, although I think he just wanted to make the program run.